# Get comment tag from XML attribute with Bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I understand how to retrieve XML content within regular nodes, but I would like to understand how to retrieve content within a comment tag in XML using Bash.

For example, consider the below XML snippet:

```
    <ParentTag1><!--This comment is associated to ParentTag1 -->
       <ChildTag1>ChildTag1Blah</ChildTag1><!-- ChildTag1 comment-->
       <ChildTag2><!-- ChildTag2 comment -->
          <GrandchildTag1>GrandchildTag1Blah</GrandchildTag1><!-- GrandchildTag1 comment-->
          <GrandchildTag2>GrandchildTag2Blah</GrandchildTag2><!-- GrandchildTag2 comment-->
       </ChildTag2>
   </ParentTag1>
```

I'd like to know how to retrieve the comment associated to the node in question. For example, given `ParentTag1`, what command can I run to retrieve the "This comment is associated to ParentTag1" comment? Similarly for the other nodes.

I have used `xmlstarlet` in the past to retrieve content within the nodes, but I'm not entirely sure if the same would be used to retrieve content within a comment in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The retrieve comments, use the `comment()` node selector.
To get the "This comment is associated to ParentTag1" comment you can use

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/comment()[1]" input.xml
```

To chose from all descendant comments, use the `descendant::comment()` axis like this

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/descendant::comment()" input.xml
```

**Result is:**

```
This comment is associated to ParentTag1 
ChildTag1 comment
ChildTag2 comment 
GrandchildTag1 comment
GrandchildTag2 comment
```

After that, you can index the comment you want (or use another axis).

Comment: Thank you. The command runs fine for comments within the tags, but not for those where the comment is after the closing tag. For example, your answer works for ParentTag1 as the comment is within its closing tag, but doesn't work for ChildTag1 or GrandchildTag1 as the comments appear after the closing tag. How would you solve this?

Comment: I added a more complete solution to the answer. It encompasses all `comment()` children of `ParentTag1`.

Comment: Thank you! But how would I do it if I wanted to run separate commands to retrieve each comment individually rather than a list of all the descendants?

Comment: To achieve this, run a command for each index: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/descendant::comment()[1]" input.xml` for the first, `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/descendant::comment()[2]" input.xml` for the second and so on...

Comment: is there any way I can specify to retrieve the comment given the specific path? For example, given ParentTag1/ChildTag2/GrandchildTag1 and retrieve the comment associated? The code I'm working with gets a bit tedious if I have to find all the child nodes and loop through each comment.

Comment: For the given path, you can use `//ParentTag1/ChildTag2/GrandchildTag1/following::comment()`. Its result is, as expected, "GrandchildTag1 comment".

Comment: The result is actually:
"GrandchildTag1 comment
GrandchildTag2 comment"
Do you know why that is?

Comment: It seems like the command is getting all the sibling and child node comments. I believe that's what the "following" might indicate.

Comment: You can, as before, use an index to only get the first result: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/ChildTag2/GrandchildTag1/following::comment()[1]" input.xml`. This returns only the `GrandchildTag1 comment`.

Comment: The problem with this is if I remove the comment for GrandchildTag1 and run the same command, it picks up the GrandchildTag2 comment (even when I'm specifying GrandchildTag1 in the xmlstarlet command). Would you get the same?

Comment: You can use `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ParentTag1/ChildTag2/GrandchildTag1/following::node()[1][self::comment()]" input.xml`. It selects the first node following the `GrandchildTag1` element and only prints the result if it's a comment().

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That works. But just FYI, that command doesn't seem to work if the comment exists within the tag (i.e. before the node closing tag). So I've had to combine the command in your answer and the command you've specified in your previous comment. Thank you for all your help!