# Executing a script takes so long on Git Bash

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash

I'm currently executing a script on Git Bash on a Windows 7 VM. The same script is executed within 15-20 seconds on my Mac machine, but it takes almost 1 hour to run on my Windows.

The script itself contains packages that extract data from XML files, and does not call upon any APIs or anything of the sort.

I have no idea what's going on, and I've tried solving it with the following answers, but to no avail:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/738493
- https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Diagnosing-performance-issues

I would like to have someone help me out in diagnosing or giving a few pointers on what I could do to either understand where the issue is, or how to resolve it altogether.

**EDIT:**
I am not able to share the entire script, but you can see the type of commands that the script uses through previous questions I have asked on Stackoverflow. Essentially, there is a mixture of [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) commands that are used.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694678/3480297
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693691/3480297
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080702/3480297

**EDIT2:**
As a high level overview, the script essentially loops over a folder for XML files, and then retrieves certain data from each one of those files, before creating an HTML page and pasting that data in tables.

A breakdown of these steps in terms of the code can be seen below:

**Searching folder for XML files and looping through each one**

```
for file in "$directory"*
do
    if [[ "$file" == *".xml"* ]]; then
        filePath+=( "$file" )
    fi
done

for ((j=0; j < ${#filePath[@]}; j++)); do

    retrieveData "${filePath[j]}"

done
```

**Retrieving data from the XML file in question**

```
function retrieveData() {
    filePath=$1

    # Retrieve data from the revelent xml file
    dataRow=$(xml sel -t -v "//xsd:element[@name=\"$data\"]/@type" -n "$filePath")

    outputRow "$dataRow"
}
```

**Outputting the data to an HTML table**

```
function outputRow() {
    rowValue=$1

    cat >> "$HTMLFILE" << EOF
        <td>
            <div>$rowValue</div>
        </td>
EOF
}
```

As previously mentioned, the actual xml commands used to retrieve the relevant data can differ, however, the links to my previous questions have the different types of commands used.

Comment: Show us your script.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica I am not able to do that but I have modified my questions to help better. Also, I have specified that the script takes almost no time running on a Mac so may it's not the script that's the issue (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Please, you need to show code. If you need to strip it down and anonymize it, do so. Describing code in words is a non-starter.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica it's not just that the code is confidential, but it's also quite big (multiple files). It's not just as easy as pasting it here. Is there anything in particular that you'd like to see other than what I've posted in my question?

Comment: While I don't have a git bash setup on Windows, I've observed that shell scripts running in both WSL on Win10 and and in a MSYS2 environment do take considerably longer to run compared to on other OSes. I *think* it has something to do with Windows taking more time to start processes (Something shell scripts do a lot of), and/or Windows Defender, but I've never cared enough to really narrow down the cause.

Comment: @Shawn thank you. Do you think there is any way to avoid Windows starting unnecessary processes or anything of the sort?

Comment: Write your programs in languages that aren't built around doing 95% of the job via executing other programs? Use a linux/unix setup instead of Windows?

Comment: You need to spend some time to create a [mre]. It may take a few hours and a lot of trial and error but it's what you have to do. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385640/68587.

Comment: "I understand that narrowing down the relevant details and recording them in an easy to follow format are a lot of work, but imagine trying to do that work if you're trying to answer the question. If you're an answerer, you can only guess about what the asker's environment looks like; anything you try will be purely a shot in the dark. The people looking to answer your question are strangers who are graciously offering their time; it's not really very polite to ask them to chase down the problem without having any way to verify their ideas about the cause."

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica that's a fair statement. I've seen other examples (that I've linked in my question) where people are also having issues with Git Bash being slow, it I thought it may be something similar and was hoping to get similar answers. But I suppose that's quite hard without seeing any code. However, another reason I'm hesitant to share the code is because the script runs perfectly fine on my Mac, and therefore, it seems to be something more specific to Windows than anything else.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica please have a look at snippets of the code (anonymised)

Answer (score 1):

Your `git-bash` installation is out of date.

Execute `git --version` to confirm this.  Are you using something from before 2.x?

Please install the [latest version of git-bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win), which is 2.24.0 as of 2019-11-13.

See the [Release Notes for git](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) for more information about performance improvements over time.